# transaction log backup file size

Tags: database-backups

After setup transaction log backup on sql server 2012, log file size still growing and when I shinked log file still same size. If I assign max file size to log file what will happen? how can I prevent to grow log file size then 1 gb.

or what is best practice of transaction log backup hourly?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the [“Understanding Logging and Recovery in SQL Server”](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx) Paul S. Randal has given a complete overview of the transaction log as a topic. That is a good starting point for learning all about transaction log and maintenance. Consider switching to SIMPLE recovery model. There are some common misconceptions about the transaction log: Transaction log truncation will not make a transaction log smaller, transaction log records are not written to the data storage immediately, transaction log shrinking is not a good practice, a transaction log will grow if its database is in the simple recovery model etc. More on this topic in [post](http://blog.sqlxdetails.com/transaction-log-myths/) by Vedran Kesegic